# How to override default parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've found lots of creative ways to set default parameters in ES5 & ES6 but I have yet to see a simple example of how to override default parameters in JavaScript. Take this example:

`new Connection(host, port = 25575, password, timeout = 5000)`

The default timeout is fine but the port number is not. When calling this function, JavaScript always treats the second parameter as the `password` parameter:

```
myConnection = connFactory.getConnection(process.env.IP,
                                         process.env.PORT,
                                         process.env.PASSWORD)
```

This code results in an authentication error because the second parameter is assumed to be `password`. How can I override the default parameter for `port` **without** modifying the original function definition?

Comment: `new Connection(host, port = 25575, password, timeout = 5000)` what kind of syntax is this? Can you show us a more complete example of your code? We have no idea what `getConnection` looks like, so how can we help you with it?

Comment: Wrap the function in your own function, which allows you to change the order of parameters.

Comment: This should not be that case. In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wd1oh8o7/), the default parameter are corretly use and the second parameter is used as `port`. So I would guess the problem is somewhere else. Please create a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: how does `getConnection` look like? It sounds like there is something wrong into `getConnection` rather than default values

Comment: I believe the question is about parameter's ordering rather than overriding default parameter value

Comment: My guess is that the implementation will check the number of passed arguments and handle three parameters as (host, password, timeout).

Comment: I know you cannot reorder the parameters, but as far as I know, it's a good practice to think about their order when you design a function since it matters a lot in JS. It does not feel right to set the mandatory parameter `password` after an optional parameter. Semantically, it's more important (since mandatory), so it must be set before. Moreover, it allows to prevent that kind of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a *config* object as a parameter for your function. For example:

```
function foo({a='SO', b}) {
  console.log(a, b)
}

foo({b: 'Yeap', a: 'baz'}) // baz Yeap
foo({b: 'foo'}) // SO foo
```

It will guarantee your ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'getConnection' isn't your function but comes from some unreachable for you place, here is one of a few solutions that will guarantee to be working. It is a function which task is to prepare all parameters.

```
function getConnectionRunner(host, password, optional = {port: 25575, timeout: 5000}) {
  const port = optional.port || 25575;
  const timeout = optional.timeout || 5000;

  connFactory.getConnection(host, port, password, timeout);
}
```